# Spring form multiple binding

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Hi guys is it possible to bind selected value and label at the same time on spring form?

I am trying something similar to that.

```
<form:select id="selectionCity" path="targetAddress.cityid"
                        multiple="false">
                        <form:options itemValue="cityid" itemLabel="cityname" />
                        <form:hidden path="targetAddress.cityname" itemValue="cityname" />
                    </form:select>
```

I am stuck here

Comment: do you get any error? what output do you get?

Comment: I don't have any error, it is just a demostration, I was just asking if there is a way to accomplish it.. Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I had to do it with javascript.

```
<script language="Javascript">
    function saveTarget() {
        $('#hiddenCity').val($('#selectionCity :selected').text());
    }
</script>
```

and the html side is like that

```
<form:hidden path="targetAddress.cityname" id="hiddenCity" />
```

seems messy but works just fine....

Answer (score 1):

IMHO it's not a Spring problem - it's HTML question.

Just ask yourself how would you do it in HTML? You could try combining the value and label into single string using predefined separator and using id as a value. But this would require manual parsing on the server side.

Anyway why would you bind label? Label should be derivable from unique value, so it should be enough to bind value only.

Comment: Hey Roadrunner! 

No, It indeed is spring problem because I am binding the itemValue in <form:options> and <spring:bind> I need to bind the label too just the value on its own isn't enough. I don't want manual parsing I am just asking if multiple binding is possible. I guess it is not possible. Thanks for the answer. Much appreciated.